# Bitwise multiplication and division not working with large numbers

Tags: c, bit-manipulation

I'm trying to get this problem to work where I have to multiply 3/8 in bit and then round towards zero.

So far I have this

```
((((x<<1)+x)>>3)+((x>>31)&1));
```

The idea behind it is that the first part takes x and shifts it left 1 and adds x to get the multiplied by 3 effect and then shifts right 3 to get the divide by 8 part. Then I would add 1 if it is negative by testing to see if the sign bit is 1 (1&1 = 1) or 0 (0&1 = 0). My code won't work though, the tests are off.

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Comment: What do you actually get as a result and what value are you testing.

Comment: @sabbahillel RIght now I testing -2147483648 [0x80000000] and get -268435455 and the right answer is -268435456

Comment: Provide a [mcve]. As it looks that will invoke both: _undefined_ and _implementation defined behaviour_ for certain constellations. Why do you try to optimise manually? Does the compiler not optimise readable code properly? Its that relevant? Did you benchmark? Unless you have answerd all these questions (and possibly some I just forgot to ask), you should not do premature optimisations.

Comment: @harlod I don't understand. The question calls for rounding AFTER you multiply by 3/8ths. I have absolutely no idea what to do anymore

Comment: @user3483844 never mind I interpreted it badly. Though in general, rounding "after" something has been done is only a way to describe the result, not a way to actually do it.

Answer (score 0):

The left shifts that you use in effect shifts the individual bits as an **unsigned integer** so that you could wind up losing the sign bit. That is not what it sounds like you want. Try the multiplication to see what you should be getting against the bit shift to see what you are getting.

```
x *= 3.0/8.0;
```

Note the manual entry below showing that if the signed bit is affected the result **is undefined**

[Left shift](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/336xbhcz.aspx)

> The left-shift operator causes the bits in shift-expression to be
>   shifted to the left by the number of positions specified by
>   additive-expression. The bit positions that have been vacated by the
>   shift operation are zero-filled. A left shift is a logical shift (the
>   bits that are shifted off the end are discarded, including the sign
>   bit). For more information about the kinds of bitwise shifts, see
>   Bitwise shifts.
>
> The following example shows left-shift operations using unsigned
>   numbers. The example shows what is happening to the bits by
>   representing the value as a bitset. For more information, see bitset
>   Class.
>
> **If you left-shift a signed number so that the sign bit is affected, the result is undefined**. The following example shows what happens in
>   Visual C++ when a 1 bit is left-shifted into the sign bit position.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <bitset>
using namespace std;

int main() {
  short short1 = 16384;    
  bitset<16> bitset1{short2};
  cout << bitset1 << endl;  // 0100000000000000 

  short short3 = short1 << 1;
  bitset<16> bitset3{short3};  // 16384 left-shifted by 1 = -32768
  cout << bitset3 << endl;  // 100000000000000

  short short4 = short1 << 14;
  bitset<16> bitset4{short4};  // 4 left-shifted by 14 = 0
  cout << bitset4 << endl;  // 000000000000000  
}
```

Comment: The left shift works, though, and does what he expects. His problem is simple overflow. But sure, at some point he has to confront loss of the sign bit. On virtually every CPU ever made, this is all predictable. The standard punts with *undefined* so as to permit machines that don't use 2's complement, but it's not really the problem here.

Comment: Another way to phrase this is that he is not programming to the standard, kind of by necessity.  He is using C to manipulate specifically two's complement values, given that it apparently should produce correct results on negative numbers. And that's fine, many many lines of code have been written that do just that, standards or no standards.

Answer (score 0):

You are overflowing your format by testing with the most negative number and then trying to multiply it to a larger (i.e., even more negative) number.

There are various ways to fix this.

1. Use something larger like int64.
2. Use a second value to hold the overflow.
3. Split the value in half and then compute it as a polynomial.

For the one test case, you could divide first and then multiply, and it would "work", but it would fail for all the cases where you then lose bits off the right side.

Comment: Is the problem the left shift? Can I just change it to x+x+x instead of ((x << 1) + x)

Comment: You only have 32-bits to work with. That's the problem. There isn't an easy way to fix this, but every way that will work starts with truely understanding the problem. Start printing your values with `%08x` and you should start to see that your shifts are simply causing bits to fall off the end.

Comment: And read up on the 2's complement binary signed number representation, by far the most widely used radix complement.  You need to understand what the bit strings mean and how you are always working with a finite number of bits.